# JavaScript ISBN Validation Issues

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, typeerror

I'm working on a webpage that has a form (for a book wishlist) that will eventually be set to input data to a MySQL database and I'm trying to set up a "10 or 13 digit ISBN" number validation script. The way the page and the script should work is: (1) When a user fills out the form and forgets to enter any info, the page will put out a "This field is required" text bubble. However, when the user mistypes the ISBN number, it should (on submit) run the ISBN validation, then blurt out the error saying it's an incorrect ISBN. Here is my work so far(the PHP "includes" won't show because those contain the logo, nav-bar, header, footer, etc. Let me know if you need those also):

My webpage:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="nojs html css_verticalspacer" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="generator" content="2018.0.0.379"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Home</title>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="scripts/isValidISBN.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css?crc=160364092" id="pagesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="clearfix borderbox" id="page"><!-- group -->
    <?php include 'templates/header and nav-bar.php'; ?>
    <?php include 'templates/pictbox.php'; ?>
    <div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block" style="width: 75px;right: 30px;">
        <form method="post" onsubmit="return function isISBN(str)" name="vform">
        <br id="data">
        <label>Categories:</label>
        <select title="categoryID">
            <option value="1">Arts & Photography</option>
            <option value="2">Children’s Books</option>
            <option value="3">Computers & Technology</option>
            <option value="4">Science & Math</option>
        </select>
            <br>
        <label for="book_title">Book Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="book_title" required id="book_title"/>
        <br>
        <label for="author">Author:</label>
        <input type="text" name="author" required id="author"/>
        <br>
        <label for="isbn">ISBN:</label>
        <input type="text" name="isbn" required id="isbn"/>
        <div id="isbn_error" class="isbn_error"></div>
        <br>
    <label for="description">Description:</label>
    <textarea name="description" required id="description"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php include 'templates/footer.php'; ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript:

```
    function assertString(input) {
    var isString = typeof input === 'string' || input instanceof String;

    if (!isString) {
        throw new TypeError('This library (validator.js) validates strings only');
    }
}

var isbn10Maybe = /^(?:[0-9]{9}X|[0-9]{10})$/;
var isbn13Maybe = /^(?:[0-9]{13})$/;
var factor = [1, 3];

function isISBN(str) {
    var version = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : '';

    assertString(str);
    version = String(version);
    if (!version) {
        return isISBN(str, 10) || isISBN(str, 13);
    }
    var sanitized = str.replace(/[\s-]+/g, '');
    var checksum = 0;
    var i = void 0;
    if (version === '10') {
        if (!isbn10Maybe.test(sanitized)) {
            return false;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            checksum += (i + 1) * sanitized.charAt(i);
        }
        if (sanitized.charAt(9) === 'X') {
            checksum += 10 * 10;
        } else {
            checksum += 10 * sanitized.charAt(9);
        }
        if (checksum % 11 === 0) {
            return !!sanitized;
        }
    } else if (version === '13') {
        if (!isbn13Maybe.test(sanitized)) {
            return false;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            checksum += factor[i % 2] * sanitized.charAt(i);
        }
        if (sanitized.charAt(12) - (10 - checksum % 10) % 10 === 0) {
            return !!sanitized;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When the validation script is run the developer tools of my browser throws the exception that I've setup. What do you think I can do?

Comment: It would help if you told us exactly what isn't working. Have you looked at the console output? If so, what errors do you see there?

Comment: According the developer source window on my browser, it's crapping on line 6 of the script (isbn = isbn.replace( /-/g, "") with the error "Type Error: isbn.replace is not a function. That line is supposed to remove any "dash" symbols in the typed isbn number.

Comment: Edit your question and add in that information.

Comment: It's done. I've also tried  to change (/-/g, "") to (/[^\dX]/gi, '') but did not work either.

Comment: I tried the code in fiddle and received this message: {"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-author', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x7f0a04e4e850>, 'html_name': 'author', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_author', 'label': u'Author', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at

Comment: 0x7f0a04e4e250>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'author'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x7f0a04e4e850>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x7f0a04f0ef10>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x7f0a04e4e850>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field':

Comment: <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x7f0a04f0e250>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}